# retrieving varchar from postgres using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

from table country in postgres :

```
id  country_code country_desc
1   US           United States
2   GB           United Kingdom
3.  GR           Greece
4   CA           Canada
```

i retrieve column `country_code` using sqlalchemy.My db is set to utf-8:

```
 engine = sql.create_engine(connectionString)
    countries = engine.execute('select country_code from country')
    for country in countries:
        print(country)
```

which returns:

```
('US',)
('GB',)
('GR',)
('CA',)
```

instead of

```
    US
    GB
    GR
    CA
```

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```html
countries.country_code or countries.["country_code"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 engine = sql.create_engine(connectionString)
    countries = engine.execute('select country_code from country')
    for country in countries:
        print(country[0])
```

did the job